# Moving feature using Python console in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, qgis-python-console

I am building a QGIS plugin that can create as much copies of a selected feature as I want and paste it to my required place.I have code to copy and paste feature

```
select = iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()

if self.i==0:
    iface.actionCopyFeatures().trigger()
    self.i=1
else:
    iface.actionPasteFeatures().trigger()
```

On first click it copies the feature and on second click it paste it and so on. But my problem is I want to paste it on my required place just like I am moving feature from one place to another.

Can you tell me how to move feature and also how to perform this whole task?

I am using this with cursor click so I want to know also how to get feature on my cursor on first click so I can easily paste it on my required place.